# How to install Haskell Platform on Linux Debian Wheezy?

Tags: linux, haskell, debian, ghc, haskell-platform

Initially I thought I would get install Haskell with couple of commands using apt-get but its seems somehow complex.

As I look at the [haskell org download page](http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html), I downloaded  `haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0.tar.gz`. Then next step is somehow confusing. It ask to install `GHC` before installing platform but at the same time if one opens GHC download page , it shows some warning e.g `Stop ! ..... we recommend installing the Haskell Platform instead of GHC`.

Please guide me how to install Haskell on Debian Wheezy. Can we build a `.deb` installation package from this package ?

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install haskell-platform [haskell-platform-doc]`

Comment: @vivan could you make that an answer ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`$ sudo apt-get install haskell-platform [haskell-platform-doc]`

On Debian Jessie, the above will install an outdated Haskell distribution. The latest can still be installed by downloading the ["generic" Linux tarball](https://www.haskell.org/platform/#linux-generic) for the Haskell platform.