# Installing Haskell in Debian (Wheezy) 2015

Tags: haskell, debian, cabal

How do I install the Haskell Platform in Debian?
unfortunately, `deb.haskell.org` isn't working.
If there is no way to install the platform, then how do I install the most up to date versions of `GHC` and `Cabal` with `apt-get`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415328/how-to-install-haskell-on-linux-debian-wheezy/18415472#18415472

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Haskell Platform for Linux](https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html) ?

Using the Generic Linux Binaries, you can get the [2014.2.0.0 version of Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/platform/download/2014.2.0.0/haskell-platform-2014.2.0.0-unknown-linux-x86_64.tar.gz) instead of the [2012.2.0.0 community version](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=haskell-platform).

I use the Generic Linux Binaries on Ubuntu 12 and 14 without any problem. It is designed for Deb 7 systems, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Debian has a `haskell-platform` package in the main repository, though the version in Wheezy isn't the latest (as is common for a stable release with long-term support).  That's the easiest and most convenient way to install Haskell in Debian, and it's supported e.g. with security updates for the life of the Wheezy release.  Consider using that unless you specifically need a newer version.

Also, note that a new version of Debian (Jessie) is likely to be released in the next few months.  That includes a newer version of the `haskell-platform` package.