# How can I install a recent version of the Haskell GHC compiler on Ubuntu?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I noticed that I'm running an old version of GHC on Ubuntu 15.04. Can I get a newer one without having to compile it from source?

Comment: If [`ghc-7.8` from the Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) is too old for your tastes, you can get [7.10 binaries right from the GHC page](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_1).

Comment: If you are familiar with Stackage and comfortable with using `.cabal` files I would use `stack`. Instructions are [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Downloads)

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I have 7.6.3, and when I try `sudo apt-get install haskell-platoform`, it says `haskell-platform is already the newest version.`

Comment: @Jono: alright, Vivid15.04 still has the 2013 Haskell platform (Wily15.10 will [change that](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/haskell-platform)). But you can easily [install the 2014 one by hand](https://www.haskell.org/platform/download/2014.2.0.0/haskell-platform-2014.2.0.0-unknown-linux-x86_64.tar.gz).

Comment: there is a ppa: `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu trusty main` from Herbert V. Rieder for this: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc - I think it's the easiest way if you don't want to compile it yourself ;)

Comment: Another way would be to use nix-package manager. You can get built binary of compiler and nearly all of the Haskell packages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415328/how-to-install-haskell-on-linux-debian-wheezy/18415472#18415472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a PPA with prepackaged binaries for many recent versions of GHC.

1. Add the following to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra-ppas.list` file:

   `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu vivid main 
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/hvr/ghc/ubuntu vivid main`
2. Install one of the PPA's versions of GHC. They are named `tool-version` while the ones that come with Ubuntu are simply named `tool`. The most recent at the time of this writing is `ghc-7.10.2`, for example.
3. GHC will be installed under `/opt/ghc/<version>/bin`. Add this folder to your path to use that version of GHC.

Comment: You can also download the binary distribution from here: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_10_1#x86_64linux. That allows you to have multiple versions of GHC on your system.

Comment: does this uninstall the installed version before installing the new one ?

Comment: PPA page with more info: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc

Answer (score 11):

I highly recommend using [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). It has made my life 110% easier and solves your problem.

You can get `GHC 7.8` with 1106 packages that won't break (no cabal hell, no cabal sandbox install marathons) or you can get `GHC 7.10` with 1028 packages - [source](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/04/update-ghc-7-10-stackage).

You can even run different versions of `GHC` in different projects! Check the [FAQ](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/FAQ) for details. To install if you are on an Ubuntu system, follow the [installation docs](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/Downloads#ubuntu).

**Edit**: Just tried to create a new `stack` project with `GHC 7.10` and there was a bit more to it than first expected. After installing `stack` you will run:

```
stack new
```

Then, you'll need to edit your `stack.yaml`, and change the default resolver from

```
resolver: lts-2.19
```

to:

```
resolver: ghc-7.10
```

Then you can run:

```
stack setup
```

Or

```
stack build --install-ghc  # to build as well!
```

and you will have a new `stack` project with `GHC 7.10`. Reference for `stack.yaml` is [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/stack.yaml).

Comment: Is not `stack setup` aimed to do the setup job after changing anything in `stack.yaml` including ghc version?

Comment: @foki `stack build --install-ghc` will install GHC and build your project, while `stack setup` will only install GHC. So I suppose I should change my answer to be more exact. We only want the compiler in this question. EDIT: Oh wait, I'll do both ;) Thanks!